# Google Script to search for embedded url with "text to display" changed from URL

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm in the process of moving from a personal My Drive to a Team Drive.  I now understand that if document has an embedded url link to a google drive folder that the link will be broken. (Side note:  embedded links direct to documents do not break on the move.)Does anyone have a script that I can execute to return all files that have an embedded url link to a folder when the "Text to Display" has been changed from the url address?  I've used the basic google drive search feature to return all files with embedded link where the "text to display" is still the url. Help appreciated.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.